# Events doesn't correctly trigger when new elements are added

Tags: jquery

I'm facing a problem, There is a page with 2 `div sections` `section-1` and `section-2`. `section-1` is called `landscape` and `section-2` is called `portrait`.
 Page has an `unordered list` and every `list item` is associated with a separate div class `.content`.
 By default `.content`class has a property which is set to`display none`. But when events like `mouseenter, mouseleave` or `click` is occur, a class with the name `.active` which has a property `display block` is added on that div then div display is block and associated div.content of list item is show on screen.

**Landscape mode**

When width of the page is greater than `754` then it means it's a landscape mode now `unordered list` can only trigger `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` events.
 When user is hover on `list item` then class with the name `.active` is added to that `list item` also on associated div.

**Portrait mode**

But when width of the page is less than `754` then it's on `portrait` mode.
 **What happens if the page is by default loaded on landscape mode and we try to resize window to make it explicitly portrait .**

Html code of `section-1` which is so called `unordered list` of `landscape mode` is transfer to `div section-2` with some minor look and feel changes.

**What are minor look and feel changes**.

[image: Minor changes]

Now in `portrait` mode only `click` event is trigger when user `click` on list item then same thing happen class with the name `.active` is added to that `list item` also on associated div.
 But there is a problem these events only works for first time when page is load. But when window is resize and html code transfer to another section and vice versa events doesn't occur.

What I mean is after resizing window, In `portrait mode` `click` event is doesn't trigger or on `landscape mode` `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` events are not trigger. What i'm doing wrong.

```js
;(function ($, window, document) {
    // Global Variables
    var flagBreakPoint = true; // Boolean flag for events
    var currentListItem;
    var currentDivContent;
    var allLists; // value assign through function refreshListItems()
    var allContentdivs; // value assign through function refreshListItems()



    $(document).ready(function () {
        allLists.on('mouseenter', function () {
            if (flagBreakPoint) {
                // get current list item
                currentListItem = $(this);
                // get current div content
                currentDivContent = $(allContentdivs[$(this).index() - 1]);
                // remove .active class from all list items
                allLists.removeClass('active');
                // add class on current list item
                $(this).addClass('active');
                // remove .active class from all content divs
                allContentdivs.removeClass('active');
                // add .active class on current content div which associative with list item
                currentDivContent.addClass('active');

            }
        }).on('mouseleave', function () {
            if (flagBreakPoint) {
                // remove .active class from all list items
                allLists.removeClass('active');
                // remove .active class from all content divs
                allContentdivs.removeClass('active');
            }
        }).on('click', function () {
            if (!flagBreakPoint) {
                // get current list item
                currentListItem = $(this);
                // get current div content
                currentDivContent = $(allContentdivs[$(this).index()]);
                // remove .active class from all list items
                allLists.removeClass('active');
                // add class on current list item
                $(this).addClass('active');
                // remove .active class from all content divs
                allContentdivs.removeClass('active');
                // add .active class on current content div which associative with list item
                currentDivContent.addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });


    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        refreshListItems(this);
    });


    var refreshListItems = function (window) {
        if (window.innerWidth > 754) {
            // Portrait to Landscape
            transferHtmlfromSec2toSec1();
            // get all list items except first one
            allLists = $('.ul-container').children('li:not(:first-child)');
            // get all div contents
            allContentdivs = $('.content');


            // remove .active class from all list items
            allLists.removeClass('active');
            // remove .active class from all content divs
            allContentdivs.removeClass('active');
            // boolean for landscape
            flagBreakPoint = true
        } else {
            // Landscape to portrait
            transferHtmlfromSec1toSec2();
            // get all list items
            allLists = $('.ul-container').children('li');
            // get all div contents
            allContentdivs = $('.content');


            // remove .active class from all list items
            allLists.removeClass('active');
            // remove .active class from all content divs
            allContentdivs.removeClass('active');
            // boolean for portrait
            flagBreakPoint = false;
        }
    };

    var transferHtmlfromSec2toSec1 = function () {

        // add list item heading only on landscape mode if it doesn't exist
        if ($('.ul-container').find('.inactive').length === 0) {
            $('.ul-container').prepend('<li class="inactive">Categories</li>');
        }
          // if 'section-2' has a heading alter section 2 heading
        if ($('.section-2').find('.heading').length !== 0) {
            // modify h1 heading with the innerHTML 'Landscape'
            $('.section-2').find('.heading').html('Landscape');
            // get html code of 'section-2' as a string
            var str = $('.section-2').html();
            // remove original html code from 'section-2'
            $('.section-2').find('.area').remove();
            // add html code in 'section-1`
            $('.section-1').prepend(str);
        }
    };


    var transferHtmlfromSec1toSec2= function () {
        // remove list item heading
        $('.inactive').remove();
        // modify h1 heading with the innerHTML 'Portrait'
        $('.section-1').find('.heading').html('Portrait');
        // get html code of 'section-1' as a string
        var str = $('.section-1').html();
        // remove original html code from 'section-1'
        $('.section-1').find('.area').remove();
        // add html code in 'section-2'
        $('.section-2').prepend(str);
    };


})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```css
.section-1, .section-2 {
            margin: 20px 0;
            height: auto;
            min-height: 210px;

        }

        .section-1 {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        .section-2 {
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }

        .area {
            padding: 18px;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }

        .clearfix:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        .ul-container {
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .heading {
            text-align: center;
            color: crimson;
        }

        .inactive {
            color: crimson;
            list-style: none;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: cornflowerblue;
        }

        /* Active class on list items */
        .ul-container li.active {
            color: orange;
        }

        .content-container {
            width: 80%;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }

        .content {
            color: #737171;
            display: none;
        }

        /* Active class on div contents */
        .content.active {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="section-1">
    <div class="area clearfix">
        <h1 class="heading">Landscape</h1>
        <ul class="ul-container">
            <li class="inactive">Categories</li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="content-container">
            <div class="content">
                Category 1 Content : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Category 2 Content : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Category 3 Content : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Category 4 Content : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
                printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
                type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
                including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please reduce the problem to a [mcve]. That makes it **dramatically** easier for people to help you (and markedly increases the chances they'll try).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i'm Refactoring my jquery code.